# Implementation of the Freemarker Debugger api

Tags: debugging, freemarker

I am working on a tool/plugin for debugging freemarker templates and was wondering if there is an example implementation for this api.

Comment: Just process the template and see if any exceptions are thrown

Answer (score 1):

The debugging API it has (as of 2.3.31) was never properly finished, and is abandoned for some 10+ years. Though I think basic breakpoints did work with it, I would say, no, there is no viable debugging support.

Comment: thanks for your answer. debugging could be very useful since Freemarker is now used in so many transformation solutions.